# Como configurar .htaccess e PHP para usar URL amigável com parâmetros

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Configurei o meu `.htaccess` para usar as `URL Amigáveis` no site que estou desenvolvendo, mas estou com uma dificuldade em passar e receber parâmetros, pela regra que defini tudo o que é digitado na URL está passando pela minha index, quando não tenho parâmetros a página que está sendo chamada é exibida corretamente mas quando tento passar um parâmetros para uma página ela caia na exceção do meu `IF` e vai para a página `404` pois o script entende que é uma página e essa página não existe.

Por exemplo:

O  meu .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ projeto.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ao chamar a página sobre-nos

```
<a target="_blank" href="sobre-nos">NOSSA HISTÓRIA</a>
```

Na minha index.php o script está assim:

```
$rotaURL = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url']:'home';
$rotaURL = array_filter(explode('/', $rotaURL));
$pagina = $rotaURL[0].'.php';
            
if(is_file($pagina)){
    
    include("inc-topbar.php");
    include("inc-cabecalho.php");
    
    // INCLUI SLIDER SE FOR A PÁGINA PRINCIPAL
    if ($pagina == 'home.php') {
        include("inc-slider.php");  
    }
    
    include($pagina);
    
} else {
    
    include("inc-topbar.php");
    include("inc-cabecalho.php");   
    include '404.php';
    
}
```

A página Sobre Nós é exibida corretamente, mas se tento chamar a página do Projeto Olho D´Agua dessa forma, ela não é reconhecida e cai no 404.

```
<a target="_blank" href="projeto/1">PROJETO OLHO D´AGUA</a>
```

A segunda regra do meu .htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ projeto.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Também tentei recuperar as variáveis para verificação, dessa forma:

```
if (isset($_GET['id')) {
    // AÇÃO DE ACORDO COM O PARÂMETRO
}
```

Entendo que a regra está configurada de forma incorreta, mas já tentei muitas alternativas que encontrei em minhas pesquisas e todas não deram certo.

Comment: *pela regra que defini tudo o que é digitado na URL está passando pela minha index* começou muito bem, mas poderia continuar assim e tratar todas suas URLs com PHP. Crie um sistema de rotas com regex para parâmetros dinâmicos e abandone essa ideia de criar suas rotas direto no htaccess... Acredito que será bem mais eficiente. Até mesmo pela facilidade de vincular essas rotas a um banco de dados e administrá-las em um painel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse conteúdo vai lhe ajudar bastante, eu estava com a mesma dificuldade e pior eu queria mais de um parametro:
"http://site/pagina1/pagina2" eu queria pegar as páginas
$page1, $page2... e só consegui após esse htaccess:

```bsh
//usando URL com dois parâmetros (uma string e um int)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
```

Depois da uma sacada: https://rotinadigital.net/urls/

Answer (score -6):

Não sei se foi um erro de digitação ao publicar a pergunta, mas aqui no seu IF do $_GET está faltando o fechamento do colchete.

```
if (isset($_GET['id')) {
    // AÇÃO DE ACORDO COM O PARÂMETRO
}
```

Com colchete:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // AÇÃO DE ACORDO COM O PARÂMETRO
}
```

Comment: É mais um comentário do que a resolução da pergunta.

Comment: Não posso comentar, não tenho reputação suficiente. Ainda levo downvote por tentar ajudar, assim que não consigo mesmo a reputação. :)